# Keyboard interface to wxPython listbox

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I'm using a wxPython listbox on Windows to get a choice from the user, and I would like them to be able to select an item using the ENTER key, as if they had double-clicked. I know how to do this in C or C++ using the Windows API directly, but can't seem to find how to do it using wxPython. Anyone know how? It seems like an obvious thing to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing some nuance, there wasn't much info to go on, but it sounds like you could accomplish this by catching the keydown event, matching for enter and then calling your on_doubleclick function. Unless there's an implicit double-click handling you should be good to go.

Comment: That's what I tried, but I don't seem to be catching keyboard events directed at the listbox.

Comment: Are you binding the event on the right object? The question is if you do `self.Bind(...)`, then the listbox may be eating the key before the container gets it. If you have a reference in `self.listbox` then  `self.listbox.Bind(...)` may be the solution.

Comment: You can get key events from a listbox (see the sample in the demo) but the problem in this case is that the ENTER key is usually grabbed before we can generate a key event for it, it may be used either as a navigation key or to activate the default button if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the wx.ListBox doesn't support that. Try using a one column wx.ListCtrl (in Report mode) instead.

Comment: Well, that is a bit pants! Aren't we supposed to provide keyboard interfaces as well as mouse ones? Thanks for the info, anyway.

Comment: What can I say? I asked Robin Dunn (creator of wxPython) about it on IRC and he said that if the native widget doesn't support that, then wx doesn't support that. Something to complain about to Bill Gates...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, the key is to Bind EVT_KEY_UP, rather than EVT_KEY_DOWN:

```
import wx

class myListBoxDemo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title="testing ListBox right-click")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.myListBox = wx.ListBox(self.panel,style=wx.LB_HSCROLL|wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.myListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyDownSelectedList)

        self.myListBox.Append('item 1')
        self.myListBox.Append('item 2')
        self.myListBox.Append('item 3')
        self.myListBox.Append('item 4')

        sizer.AddF(self.myListBox, wx.SizerFlags(1).Expand())
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnKeyDownSelectedList(self, event):
        print "KeyCode: %d" % event.GetKeyCode()
        print "ListBox Item Index: %d" % event.GetEventObject().GetSelection()

import wx.lib.mixins.inspection as wit
class AppWInspection(wx.App, wit.InspectionMixin):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Init()  # enable Inspection tool
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AppWInspection()    
    f = myListBoxDemo(None)
    f.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```